# Css not aplied to page in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a page where css isn't applied. i have a folder inside `templates` called animal and it contains 2 files `adopt.html.twig` and `index.html.twig` and the `base.html.twig`. Why css isn't applied to `adopt.html.twig`?.

My code is:

**`adopt.html.twig`**

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Adopt an animal!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <ul>
        <li class="articleItem">
            <img src="/dog.png" alt="article icon">
            <h4>Thanks ! </h4>
            <p>{{ animal.name }} is your new Compagnon </p>
            <button class="button"><a href="/animals">Go back</a></button>
            <button class="button"><a href="/adoptions">See adoptions</a></button>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**`base.html.twig`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% block head %}
    {% include 'partials/header.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
    {% include 'partials/footer.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI you have two closing `</html>` tags in base.html.twig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `css/style.css` is linked relative to current URL. So it works on mainpage but not for any subpage URL (In Symfony this means any controller with `@Route` other than `/`).

So if You open `https://your.domain.tld/`, browser would read `style.css` from `https://your.domain.tld/css/style.css`. But if You open `https://your.domain.tld/adopt/`, browser try to read `style.css` from `https://your.domain.tld/adopt/css/style.css`.

In Symfony this could be fixed by using

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

instead of:

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Please, read [Creating and Using Templates: Linking to Assets](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/templating.html#linking-to-assets)

Comment: The problem is that the css is working on other subpages but not on `adopt.html.twig`

Comment: In this particulary case it is probably because yue sometimes has slash `/` at the end of url of subpage and sometimes not. It's tricky to debug, but solution should work either and save Your time.